# Pass annotation title to embedded containerview when selected Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, mkannotationview

I have tried using the func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) to pass the annotation title to the embedded container view. However when i build and run, it doesn't work.

What am I doing incorrectly? Is this the right approach?

I've tried func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) see code

```
var annotationTitle = "Default"



func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){
    if let annotation = view.annotation {
        annotationTitle = annotation.title!!
    }

}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showMapContainer" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! MapDetailContainerViewController
        destination.selectedAnnotation = annotationTitle as String
    }
}
```

}

The data is being passed to the containerviewcontroller as "Deafult" instead of annotation.title value

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The container and map are shown at the same time. I want to be able to click the various map pins and have the container show information about the pin currently selected.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> The container and map are shown at the same time.

If they’re both created at the same time, then `prepare(for:sender:)` is undoubtedly getting called before `didSelect` is. You can confirm that with some breakpoints or judicious `print` statements.

So you can have `prepare(for:sender:)` save a reference to `segue.destination as? MapDetailContainerViewController` in some local variable and then `didSelect` can set `selectedAnnotation`

```
var embeddedViewController: MapDetailContainerViewController?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showMapContainer" {
        embeddedViewController = segue.destination as? MapDetailContainerViewController
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let annotation = view.annotation,
        let title = annotation.title {
            embeddedViewController?.selectedAnnotation = title
    }
}
```

Or you can bypass the `prepare(for:sender)` and just use `children` (previously called `childViewControllers`):

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView){
    if let embeddedViewController = children.first as? MapDetailContainerViewController,
        let annotation = view.annotation,
        let title = annotation.title {
            embeddedViewController.selectedAnnotation = title
    }
}
```